# Comparing lists which consists of tuples using RF

Tags: python-2.7, tuples, robotframework

Let me try to put this in a simple manner.

I have 2 lists, which look like below:

```
List1 = [('a', 1, 'low'), ('b', 10, 'high')] # --> Tuples in List
List2 = ["('a', 1, 'low')", "('b', 10, 'high')"] # --> Here the Tuples are actually of Type String.
```

`List1` is output of a SQL query. `List2` is defined by me as expected result.

I am using *Robot Framework* to compare these two lists with the Keyword `Lists Should Be Equal`. But it fails as `List2` has strings which look like Tuple.

How can I compare these two lists? Can I convert both the lists to a different variable type so that I can compare them. I am trying to avoid the python coding here.

Comment: re _"Here the Tuples are actually of Type String"_. Do you mean that the tuple is actually `["(a, 1, low)", "(b, 10, high")]`?

Comment: The tuple is (a, 1, low). I have defined the variable as "@{expected_result}   (a, 1, low), (b, 10, high) "  . Just before comparing it with List1 (Which is a output of SQL query) I convert it to List using the keyword  '${List2}=  Create List     @{expected_result}}. The comparison fails as the tuples in List2 are actually of type string.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? Are they objects? Are they strings? It is unclear _exactly_ what your data looks like, since `(a, 1, low)` is only valid if `a` and `low` are variables, in which case they can't be compared to the string `"(a, 1, low)"`.

Comment: Corrected it in the question description. 'a' and 'low' are strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what your data looks like, but since the two lists have different contents you'll have to convert one or both of them to a common format.

You could, for example, convert the first list to a string with something like this:

```
| ${actual}= | Evaluate | [str(x) for x in ${List1}]
```

I doubt that gives you exactly what you need because, again, it's unclear exactly what you need. However, the technique remains the same: use [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) to write a little bit of python code to convert one of your lists to be the same format as the other list before doing the compare.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the long procedure, i have used tuples (1,2) instead (a,1,low) #( cause name error in python). But you told its getting from SQL. Important is difference between (1,2) and (1, 2) #(space mismatch)

var.py

```html
List1 = [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

test.robot(txt file)

```html
*** Settings ***
Library     BuiltIn
Library     Collections
Variables   var.py
Library  String

*** Variables ***
@{appnd_li}

*** Test Cases ***
TEST
    #constructing List2=["(1, 2)","(3, 4)"] 

    ${List2}=   Create List     (1, 2)   (3, 4)
    
    # importing List1 from variable file
    ${len}=     Get Length  ${List1}

    #initialize empty list
    ${li}=  Create List     @{appnd_li}

    :FOR    ${I}    IN RANGE   0   ${len}
    \   ${item}=    Convert To String   ${List1[${I}]}
    \   Append To List  ${li}   ${item}
    
    Lists Should Be Equal   ${li}    ${List2}
~
```